# Create a Background for Text Field in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, background, textfield, decoration

I want to create a background for my text field in Flutter. What are the different methods I can use?
Something similar to these examples

[image: .]

[image: .]

[image: .]

Comment: Can you include your codes-snippet that you've tried so far?

Comment: I don't have bro...

Comment: Did you solve this?